# Error while connecting action to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to connect a component with matchDispatchtoProps.

```
function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({setAuthToken: actions.setAuthToken}, dispatch);
}


export default connect(matchDispatchToProps)(LogInComponent);
```

I am then calling setAuthToken from ajax request like this

```
handleLoginButtonClick() {
        var settings = {
            "async": true,
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": "https://trigger-backend.appspot.com/auth/login/",
            "method": "POST",
            "credentials": 'include',
            "headers": {
                "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            "data": {
                "password": "apurv",
                "username": "Apurv"
            },
            success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
                alert("success");
            },
        }

        $.ajax(settings).done((response) => {
            alert(response.auth_token);
            this.props.setAuthToken(response.auth_token);
            console.log('check');
            this.context.router.push('/app')
        });
```

this is my render component from where U call handleButtonClick

```
 render(){
        return (
            <div className="LoginPage">
                <div className="login-page">
                    <div className="form">
                        <form className="login-form">
                            <input id="username" type="username" placeholder="username"/>
                            <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="password"/>
                            <p className="message">Not registered? <a href="#">Request Username and Password</a></p>
                        </form>
                        <button onClick={this.handleLoginButtonClick.bind(this)}>login</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

But I am getting an error saying "dispatch is not a function". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in `mapDispatch` as the first argument to connect, when it needs to be the second argument.  You need to use `connect(null, mapDispatch)(LogInComponent)` instead.

Also, note that `connect()` supports a shorthand syntax for `mapDispatch`.  Instead of passing in an actual function, you can pass in an object with the action creators you want bound, like:

```
const {setAuthToken} = actions;
export default connect(null, {setAuthToken})(LogInComponent);
```

Comment: When I am doing connect(null, mapDispatch)(LogInComponent) then it gives me an error saying Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Comment: Sorry - the full name of the parameter is `mapDispatchToProps`, and that's the name of the function you wrote.  It's often abbreviated as `mapState`.  You should pass whatever actual function name you used to `connect`.

Comment: Please update your question with your current code, so I can see what it looks like.